# Sqlite android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException

Tags: android, sqlite

estou com seguinte erro:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@teste": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT teste@teste.com, teste FROM usuario WHERE email = 'teste@teste.com' AND senha = 'teste' ;

```
@Override
public User buscarEmailSenha(String email, String senha) {
    User user = null;
    Cursor cursor;

    String sql = sqliteHelper.NOME_TABELA + " WHERE email = '" + email
            + "' AND senha = '"+ senha +"' ;";
    String [] args = new String[] {email, senha};
    cursor = abrirBanco().query(sql, args, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        user = new User();
        user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
        user.setSenha(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("senha")));
    }

    if (cursor != null)
        fecharBanco();
        return user;
}
```

Comment: Douglas, me parece que o conteúdo de `sqliteHelper.NOME_TABELA` não está com um valor correto para construir uma consulta SQL... Poderia verificar se o conteúdo dela não deveria ser: `SELECT email, senha FROM <NOME_DA_TABELA>`?

Comment: O problema deve estar no `sqliteHelper.NOME_TABELA`

Comment: Você tem uma coluna chamada teste@teste.com nesta tabela?

Comment: Outro detalhe, se vc passa os campos como parametros   **String [] args = new String[] {email, senha};** não há necessidade de acidionar no SQL : **WHERE email = '" + email
            + "' AND senha = '"+ senha +"' ;"** . Neste caso usa-se **?** no lugar do parametro

Comment: Rafael Nena nao tenho uma coluna chamada teste@teste.com, tenho uma coluna chamada email.

Comment: Wakim ja tentei fazer dessa forma porem deu errado.

Comment: Thiago tbm tentei dessa forma não obteve sucesso

Comment: @DouglasWilliam então sua SQL está errada. Você tem que fazer: select coluna1, coluna2, coluna3 FROM tabela WHERE coluna1 (ou 2) = 'dado que você quer pesquisar';

Comment: Rafael estou fazendo seguinte: String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + sqliteHelper.NOME_TABELA + " WHERE email = '" + email + "' AND senha = '" + senha + "';"; so que ele dar erro: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range. The statement has 0 parameters. ou seja segundo índice esta fora, nao tem parâmetros, esses parâmetros não estão chegando.